# Progressive value collection within a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data similar to:

```
#Simulate some data
d = {
    "id": [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
    "action_order": [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4],
    "n_actions": [5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4],
    "seed": ['1','2','3','4','5','10','11','12','13'],
    "time_spent": [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,10.1,11.1,12.1,13.1]
    }
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I need a function that for each row will return the values from two columns (seed and time_spent) in that row AND ALL PREVIOUS ROWS within the group as a dictionary. I have attempted to use the apply function as follows but the results are not quite what I need.

```
data \
    .groupby(["profile_id"])[["artist_seed", "tlh"]] \
    .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["artist_seed"], x["tlh"]))) \
    .tolist()

data \
    .groupby("profile_id")[["artist_seed", "tlh", "action_order"]] \
    .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(list(x["artist_seed"]), list(x["tlh"]))))
```

The new DataFrame should look like this:

```
   id                            new_col
0   1                        {u'1': 0.3}
1   1             {u'1': 0.3, u'2': 0.4}
2   1  {u'1': 0.3, u'3': 0.5, u'2': 0.4}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a running `dict` and just return a copy of the most recent version on each `apply` iteration, per group:

```
def wrapper(g):
    cumdict = {}
    return g.apply(update_cumdict, args=(cumdict,), axis=1)

def update_cumdict(row, cd):
    cd[row.seed] = row.time_spent
    return cd.copy()

data["new_col"] = data.groupby("id").apply(wrapper).reset_index()[0]

data.new_col
0                                           {'1': 0.3}
1                                 {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4}
2                       {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4, '3': 0.5}
3             {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4, '3': 0.5, '4': 0.6}
4    {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4, '3': 0.5, '4': 0.6, '5': ...
5                                         {'10': 10.1}
6                             {'10': 10.1, '11': 11.1}
7                 {'10': 10.1, '11': 11.1, '12': 12.1}
8     {'10': 10.1, '11': 11.1, '12': 12.1, '13': 13.1}
Name: new_col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
In [15]: data.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda d: pd.Series(np.arange(len(d))).apply(lambda x: d[['seed', 'time_spent']].iloc[:x+1].to_dict()))
Out[15]:
id
1   0           {'seed': {0: '1'}, 'time_spent': {0: 0.3}}
    1    {'seed': {0: '1', 1: '2'}, 'time_spent': {0: 0...
    2    {'seed': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3'}, 'time_spent...
    3    {'seed': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4'}, 'ti...
    4    {'seed': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '...
2   0         {'seed': {5: '10'}, 'time_spent': {5: 10.1}}
    1    {'seed': {5: '10', 6: '11'}, 'time_spent': {5:...
    2    {'seed': {5: '10', 6: '11', 7: '12'}, 'time_sp...
    3    {'seed': {5: '10', 6: '11', 7: '12', 8: '13'},...
dtype: object
```

additionally, you can modify the parameter of .to_dict() method to change the output dict style, refer to: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

or maybe this is what you want:

```
In [18]: data.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda d: pd.Series(np.arange(len(d))).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(d['seed'].iloc[:x+1], d['time_spent'].iloc[:x+1]))))
Out[18]:
id
1   0                                           {'1': 0.3}
    1                                 {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4}
    2                       {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4, '3': 0.5}
    3             {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4, '3': 0.5, '4': 0.6}
    4    {'1': 0.3, '2': 0.4, '3': 0.5, '4': 0.6, '5': ...
2   0                                         {'10': 10.1}
    1                             {'10': 10.1, '11': 11.1}
    2                 {'10': 10.1, '11': 11.1, '12': 12.1}
    3     {'10': 10.1, '11': 11.1, '12': 12.1, '13': 13.1}
dtype: object
```